# Evolution Surge and Dispel Magic

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

The [Evolution Surge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/evolution-surge) spell series is very flexible as there are many options available. Most of the abilities granted are Ex ([extraordinary](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Extraordinary-Abilities-Ex-)) but some are Su ([supernatural](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Extraordinary-Abilities-Ex-)). How does dispel magic interact with the spell and how these abilities are granted?

My thoughts are that since they are granted by the spell, and the spell does have a duration, the spell and thus the abilities granted should be at risk from a dispel magic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your feeling is correct. It doesn’t matter that the abilities are extraordinary if the thing granting them goes away: when the spell ends, you no longer have the ability at all, regardless of what sort of ability it is. Likewise in an *antimagic field*—as long as the spell is suppressed, you don’t have that extraordinary ability.

Note, however, that it can still matter that these abilities are extraordinary or supernatural, even if spell-granted. For example, spell resistance does not apply to these abilities: even though a spell is granting the ability, the ability itself is still extraordinary or supernatural and thus spell resistance is irrelevant.